# TextView is not showing in an Activity

Tags: android, textview, visibility

I have an Activity that has some elements such as ImageViews, TextViews, EditTexts and Buttons. Everything is showing OK but two TextViews are not visible when I run the app. The preview is OK but when I open the app in my phone it doesn't show.

This is my XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="com.construct.v2.activities.auth.PasswordChangeActivity">
  <!--<include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar_simple" />-->
  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/mm_margin"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:paddingLeft="24dp"
      android:paddingRight="24dp"
      android:paddingTop="80dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/change_lock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/change_pass"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textColor="#00596f"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="2sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/change_lock"
        tools:text="@string/change_password"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textColor="#555555"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        tools:text="@string/new_password_text"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fill_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/subtitle"
        android:textColor="@color/construct_red"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        />

    <EditText
          android:id="@+id/password"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="@string/password"
          android:textSize="16dp"
          android:textColorHint="#b1b1b1"
          android:layout_below="@+id/fill_password"
          android:backgroundTint="#00596f"
          android:textColor="#00596f"
          android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
          android:inputType="textPassword"
          />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#b1b1b1"
        android:background="#e3e3e3"
        android:paddingLeft="56dp"
        android:paddingRight="56dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the preview from Android Studio:

[image]

And this is the app running in my phone:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting text with `tools`

```
tools:text="@string/new_password_text"
```

change to:

```
android:text="@string/new_password_text"
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I just found the problem. I am using Zeplin as a tool for screen designing and it usually generates the XML code for the elements. Instead of:

```
tools:text="@string/new_password_text"
```

I changed to:

```
android:text="@string/new_password_text"
```